# Sumar filas y columnas de una matriz e imprimir en una tabla

Tags: c++, array, matrices

Tengo este código que me está dando muchos problemas con la impresión de resultados y no sé como arreglarlo. Necesito que se sumen las filas y columnas de la matriz en un arreglo unidimensional para luego imprimirlo en una tabla de esta manera :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no logro poder hacer que muestre el vector de la sumatoria de las filas de manera vertical alado de la matriz que se introdujo por teclado  como se muestra  en el ejemplo

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

int matriz[4][5], horizontal[5], vertical[4], fila,columna,suma=0, i;

/*Bucle que registra los numeros introducidos de teclado*/
for(fila=1;fila<=2;fila++)
{
    for(columna=1;columna<=2;columna++)
    {
        cout<<"Introduce un numero para la posicion"<<fila<<columna<<":";
        cin>>matriz[fila][columna];
    }
}
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=2;j++){
    
    cout<<matriz[i][j]<<"  ";
    
} cout<<"\n";}


/*Bucle que suma las filas y registra el resultado en el vector vertical*/
for(fila=1;fila<=2;fila++)
{
    suma=0;
    for(columna=1;columna<=2;columna++)
    {
        suma+=matriz[fila][columna];
    }
    vertical[fila]=suma;
}

/*Recorre el vector vertical y muestra los resultados*/
for(i=1;i<2;i++)
{
   cout<<vertical[i];
}



/*Bucle que suma las columnas y registra el resultado en el vector horizontal*/
for(columna=1;columna<=2;columna++)
{
    suma=0;
    for(fila=1;fila<=2;fila++)
    {
        suma+=matriz[fila][columna];
    }
    horizontal[columna]=suma;
}

/*Recorre el vector horizontal y muestra los resultados*/
for(i=1;i<02;i++)
{
    cout<<"  "<<horizontal[i]<<"\n";
   
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Es normal que tu código te de problemas, es un código largo, innecesariamente complejo y confuso. Si separas funcionalidades en funciones (cada función debe cumplir un único objetivo) tu código será más fácil de leer, mantener y depurar.

- Para sumar filas:

  ```
  template <auto F, auto C>
  int suma_fila(int fila, const int (&matriz)[F][C])
  {
    int resultado = 0;
    for (int indice = 0; indice != C; ++indice)
        resultado += matriz[fila][indice];

    return resultado;
  }
  ```
- Para sumar columnas:

  ```
  template <auto F, auto C>
  int suma_columna(int columna, const int (&matriz)[F][C])
  {
    int resultado = 0;
    for (int indice = 0; indice != F; ++indice)
        resultado += matriz[indice][columna];

    return resultado;
  }
  ```
- Para imprimir:

  ```
  template <auto F, auto C>
  void imprime(const int (&matriz)[F][C])
  {
    for (int fila = 0; fila != F; ++fila)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : matriz[fila])
            std::cout << valor << ' ';
        std::cout << suma_fila(fila, matriz) << '\n';
    }

    for (int columna = 0; columna != C; ++columna)
        std::cout << suma_columna(columna, matriz) << ' ';
  }
  ```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
int main()
{
    int m[2][2] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    int n[4][4] = { 1, 14, 14, 4, 11, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 10, 5, 13, 2, 3, 15 };
    int o[4][3] = { 35, 60, 98, 25, 35, 65, 40, 41, 78, 21, 87, 24 };

    imprime(m);
    std::cout << '\n' << '\n';
    imprime(n);
    std::cout << '\n' << '\n';
    imprime(o);

    return 0;
}
```

Ese código genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1 1   2
> 1 1   2
> 2 2   
>
> 1     14  14  4   33
> 11    7   6   9   33
> 8     10  10  5   33
> 13    2   3   15  33
> 33    33  33  33  
>
> 35    60  98  193
> 25    35  65  125
> 40    41  78  159
> 21    87  24  132
> 121   223 265
> ```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJta4MwEP5sfsWNwVbRQWfdS2vbL4X@CScjRDsCJika@2Gjf33uzqhdYWxjMDDm7vLknnvuIvb7G1Fy/dK2l1KLsskLWEpT26rgas2YLdS@5BaDvLEGtiF0@2bNpLZQN4o/72TJJ@SREYIwurZA/uRKcVvJVz/dZukm89kb8yheFXVTWp4bWME0Yd7OVNAlkDqXouiig32xgk0CQeBcn3ne6XawAkeQEnOWOkyWMIYg21T6xJSw46@0CFM2Sjs5vf0PirY/K@q1pH0RfxF1MDIHqfaVVMXkew1jvdRIV21nDbWSg5Ui0kFdto7o6sBLDC3ORkGqvNrmi4UwjYXlEhwKjesne40dOj89vSP3hvoKHV4THpWequyb4godnOGl9L7/Jccw33G2Z0xUGRIRheJST8b5qjTK8EPCN7gNhw@OiTvWaZzhNx7HbtGG7kMI9yHMQ3hEf@rWHW6zEKIQ8H97N2YylGnmMs0QdI/YOd6L0O58XDHGYspLcdwfkSCKKQXm6MetfEx4Jp/6@KmfA1D/Fmj8T08Q3/ixbd/FruQvdXuD91ciCCL@AQ)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

hice una solución en C#, te la dejo, por si es lo que necesitas, transcríbela al lenguaje que usas. Espero te funcione

También te recomiendo utilizar los índices (0), en los arreglos.

Matriz de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
static void Main()
    {
        int[,] matriz_1 = new int[5, 4];
        int i;
        int h;

        matriz_1[0, 0] = 35;
        matriz_1[1, 0] = 25;
        matriz_1[2, 0] = 40;
        matriz_1[3, 0] = 21;

        matriz_1[0, 1] = 60;
        matriz_1[1, 1] = 35;
        matriz_1[2, 1] = 41;
        matriz_1[3, 1] = 87;

        matriz_1[0, 2] = 98;
        matriz_1[1, 2] = 65;
        matriz_1[2, 2] = 78;
        matriz_1[3, 2] = 24;

        /*SUMA VERTICAL*/
        i = 0;
        while (i<3) //recore columnas de matriz_1
        {
            h = 0;
            while (h<4) //recore filas de matriz_1
            {
                matriz_1[matriz_1.GetLength(0)-1, i] += matriz_1[h, i];

                h++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        /*SUMA HORIZONTAL*/
        i = 0;
        while (i<4) //recore filas de matriz_1
        {
            h = 0;
            while (h<3) //recore columnas de matriz_1
            {
                matriz_1[i, (matriz_1.GetLength(1) - 1)] += matriz_1[i, h];

                h++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        i = 0;
        while (i<5) //filas
        {
            h = 0;
            while (h<4) //columnas
            {
                if (i==matriz_1.GetLength(0)-1 & h == matriz_1.GetLength(1)-1 )
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.Write(" {0}", matriz_1[i, h]);

                h++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            i++;
        }



    }
```

Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El OP usa c++ y lo esperado en las respuestas es que estás estén en el mismo lenguaje